# Unable to search on sub document via dot notation in Mongo (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mongo is driving me crazy. I have these schemas:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
}
});
var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

var deviceSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true
},
type: String,
lastvalue: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'event'
},
owner: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
    require: true
},
apiKey: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    default: function() {
        return crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
    }
}
});
var Device = mongoose.model('device', deviceSchema);
```

and I want to retrieve all devices of a user. So:
`Device.find({'owner.username': req.params.username})`

But it returns an empty array!
I've also tried: 
`Device.find({'owner.username': req.params.username}, {'owner':1})`
`Device.find({'owner.username': req.params.username}, {'owner.$':1)`
Without any luck...
I've searched the whole internet but I can't find anything useful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the associated user `_id` first then query the `Device` model on the `owner` field using the `_id` from the first user query. The following shows this approach:

```
User.findOne({ "username" : req.params.username }),
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        Device
        .find({"owner": user._id})
        .populate('owner', 'username') // only return the username
        .exec(function(err, devices) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(devices, undefined, 4));
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: can I do it in a single query?